# Python Script Repeating When String Is Evaluated as Function

Tags: python

I am working on a testing environment in python to back-test several investing strategies and I am running into a consistent, if odd issue. Here is the relevant code (two functions and an input field), and below that, I'll explain the issue:

```
def strategy_names():

    strategy_name = []

    for y in range(0, n):

        z = 0

        while z == 0:

            global strategy
            strategy = input("INPUT BUY STRATEGY NAME:")

            if hasattr(Strategies, strategy):
                #strategy = "Strategies." + strategy + "()"
                strategy_name.append(strategy)
                z = 1

            else:

                print('STRATEGY NAME INCORRECT. TRY AGAIN.')
                z = 0

    strategy_name = tuple(strategy_name)
    global buy_strategy_names
    buy_strategy_names = strategy_name

def buy_strategies():

    global df_name_list
    df_name_list = []

    for y in range(0, n):

        global buy_df
        buy_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["d", "o", "h", "l", "c", "v", "di", "s"])
        global x
        x = 0

        while x <= len(dttime) - 1:

            global d, o, h, l, c, v, di, s
            d = dttime[x]
            o = float(o_price[x])
            h = float(hi[x])
            l = float(lo[x])
            c = float(c_price[x])
            v = float(vol[x])
            di = div[x]
            s = splits[x]

            while True:
                call_method = buy_strategy_names[y]
                print(call_method)
                call_method = getattr(Strategies,call_method)
                print(call_method)
                buy = call_method()
                print(buy)
                #buy = buy_strategy_names[y]
                #print('test')
                #buy = pd.eval(buy) #evaluate buy
                #print('test')
                if buy == 1:

                    new_row = {"d": d, "o": o, "h": h, "l": l, "c": c, "v": v, "di": di, "s": s}
                    buy_df = buy_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

                break

            x = x + 1

        df_name_list.append(1)
        df_name_list[y] = buy_df.copy()

    buy_result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["d", "o", "h", "l", "c", "v", "di", "s"])

    if y == 1:

        for y in range(0, len(df_name_list)):

            d = dttime[x]            ################ change variables to reference buy_df
            o = float(o_price[x])    ################ add condition for y > 1
            h = float(hi[x])
            l = float(lo[x])
            c = float(c_price[x])
            v = float(vol[x])
            di = div[x]
            s = splits[x]
            buy_df = df_name_list[y]
            buy_df_2 = df_name_list[y - 1]

            if buy_df.loc[buy_df["d"]] == buy_df_2.loc[buy_df_2["d"]]:

                new_row = {"d": d, "o": o, "h": h, "l": l, "c": c, "v": v, "di": di, "s": s}
                buy_df = buy_df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
```

These are called in the following order:

```
n = int(input("NUMBER OF BUY STRATEGIES:"))

global dttime, o_price, hi, lo, c_price, vol, div, splits

dttime = btb.datetime()
o_price = btb.open_price()
hi = btb.high()
lo = btb.low()
c_price = btb.close_price()
vol = btb.volume()
div = btb.dividends()
splits = btb.stock_splits()

strategy_names()
buy_strategies()
sys.exit()
```

Now, the problem I'm having is this: Every time I run this program, the user inputs run twice. The program asks for

```
n = int(input("NUMBER OF BUY STRATEGIES:"))
```

and

```
strategy = input("INPUT BUY STRATEGY NAME:")
```

at their proper place in the code. Then, once the line

```
buy = call_method()
```

is reached (during the execution of the buy_strategies function), it somehow loops back and requests those two user inputs again. It always asks for the inputs twice.

I have tried using eval() instead of getattr() to retrieve the function from the other module (read online that may help), however, that doesn't seem to do anything different.

In addition, occasionally when run the program, I will get runtime warnings for empty slices, though the program still runs with exit code 0. Of course, as I'm writing this post, I can't get it to produce the runtime warning to post the exact verbiage.

I know this is a LONG question and I hope it is clear enough. I'm just going out of my mind trying to peg down what is causing this program to ask for user input twice. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I know my code is probably not the cleanest, I am self taught and still very much in a learning phase, so if there's anything wildly overcomplicated in my code, please feel free to point it out!

Thank you!

Comment: It seems you took a too hard problem for your level. You need to try something more simple at first. Unlikely somebody dares to de-tangle this code. Too many global variables, rather obscured naming, and the goal of this script is not quite clear (to me at least). Or, you could try to split your algorithm into many short simple steps. The simpler the better. It's much easier to made small steps work correctly.

Comment: Makes sense. I've done a few projects of similar difficulty, but this time, I failed to use small, simple steps. Now, I'm going through and rebuilding what I've made of the program so far, but with much simpler steps. So far, so good! Thank you!

Comment: For the record, the solution to this was to have a function in another module so that circular import statements were avoided. However, I've come to the conclusion by this point that global variables are evil incarnate, so I am reworking all of my code to exclude global variables and simplifying my code wherever I can. Thank you again!